# How do I reduce polys in hair to reduce .dff file size without making .txd file buggy? (GTA SA skins)

Tags: modeling

Trying to use the decimate tool on the hair of a 3D model is fine for reducing the file size of a .dff, but then it makes the accompanying .txd file incompatible. It basically makes the skin turn black. The file sizes for both .dff and .txd need to be under 800kb for a server's custom skin import requirements. Using DragonFF's .dff scripts. Any ideas?

I've tried remeshing and other things, I just don't know exactly what I'm doing, it appears that the wire meshes are parent to each other and this is why the .txd won't apply.

https://imgur.com/TK196YX
https://imgur.com/UBMOdJ5
https://imgur.com/gL2KL2E
https://github.com/Parik27/DragonFF - the scripts for Blender
https://ufile.io/f/4pcb3 - the .dff and .txd files

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)